# Between operator Age Between Age Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

**Table One**

| Age | Students |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 |

Means
2 Students Age is 5
5 Students Age is 6 and
1 Student Age is 4

**Table Two**

| GroupName | MinAge | MaxAge | StudentsCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GroupA | 3 | 5 | 0 |
| GroupB | 5 | 7 | 0 |

Means
2 Coaching Group is there.
The first one is GroupA and the second one is GroupB
GroupA age group between 3 to 5 and
GroupB age group between 5 to 7
In this scenario there are 3 students in GroupA and 5 students in GroupB.

I want to update the StudentsCount column in table2 like GroupA = 3 and GroupB = 5

I am using between operator but the result is wrong.

```
update a
    set a.StudentsCount = b.Students 
from Table2 a, Table1 b 
where b.age between a.MinAge and a.MaxAge
```

When I am using the above query StudentsCount field update as 2 for both records. Already tried >= and <= but no luck. Anybody knows the simple table query please update. Thank you.

Comment: Your Group condition is overlapping. So Age 5 is consider Group A or B ?

Comment: You should be using an explicit join rather than an out of date comma join.

Comment: Seriously, don't use `between` its not intuitive as it includes both end conditions. Use greater than / less than (and equal if required).

Comment: *"the result is wrong"* Why is it wrong? You don't provide us with your expected results, nor tell us why the results you do get aren't correct. Though your thought process seems flawed: If `StudentsCount` have a value greater than `0` how would you know what `Age` to apply that to? If you have 5 students ages 3 to 5, what ages are they?

Comment: The construction of this data needs to looked at, one row per student is ideal.
Table One looks like the output from a query, not a table.

Comment: @DaleK update a set a.StudentsCount=b.Students from Table2 a,Table1 b where b.age>=a.MinAge and b.age<=a.MaxAge

Comment: [edit] any clarifications into the question please. And you haven't addressed squirrels point, you have overlapping criteria. Maybe it should be `b.age<a.MaxAge`

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @Evolve! I know. but in this case, there is no direct join. So I am using old-style-joins

Comment: @vinod No direct join? This makes no sense. You are joining the tables. In this case it is an inner join: `FROM table2 a INNER JOIN table1 b WHERE b.age BETWEEN a.minage AND a.maxage`. My advice: Don't ever use comma-separated joins. Always use explicit joins, which incudes that you must think about what type of join you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong approach. There is no need for a join. You want to update table2? Then `UPDATE table2`. You want to update its StudentsCount? Then `SET StudentsCount = ...`. You want the sums of the number of students? Then `SUM(Students)`.

```
UPDATE table2
SET studentscount = 
(
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(students), 0)
  FROM table1
  WHERE table1.age BETWEEN table2.minage AND table2.maxage
);
```

Two remarks:

- As others have mentioned, in your sample data you count students of age 5 twice, once in the range 3-5, once in the range 5-7. You probably want the ranges to be either 3-5 and 6-7 or 3-4 and 5-7 instead.
- We avoid redundancy in a database. You can always calculate the number of students ad hoc. You can even create a view for this. It is usually a bad idea to store the sums redundantly.